# how to update source list ubuntu17.04

Tags: apt

Hi i can not update and install with sudo apt-get update

[image]

Comment: You may consider that install programs is a stuff than only the "super user" (the admin) of the pc can do And for that reason you must to use "sudo".

Comment: I tried it too so i cant connect to internet in virtoalbox

Comment: So, your problem is not your above question. Please, changeyour question  (better: write other question) for something more specific like: "How to connect to internet my ubuntu OS in VirtualBox" or "How to install programs in Ubuntu-Virtualbox without internet connection". Not has sense to try to use apt-get update if your not have internet.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(operating_system)   Ubuntu 17.04 don't have support, so you will have more problems in the future. I recommend you to reinstall your system or upgrate. It is more advisable reinstall instead of upgrate.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead, copy-paste the text, and use the formatting tools to make it look nice. This makes it easier for more people to find and read your question. (For more details, see [Why do people post screenshots of their terminals?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/301745))

Comment: @yemino Yes, 17.04 is EOL as of this month. See also https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Answer (score 2):

You must use sudo:
`sudo apt-get update`